# Static files deployment in Spring boot using Gradle

Tags: spring, tomcat, static, war

I have a spring boot application using Gradle build system. My build.gradle is given below:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath('io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' 

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies { 
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") 
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web")
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config")
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')    
    //testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.7'
}
```

I then run from cmd, `gradle war` and I get the war file which I can successfully deploy to a tomcat instance.

I have a folder /static to serve the html as well as js files that will use the spring rest service.

The war package does not seem to contain these static files. So when I request the home page (index.html) spring returns 404 error.

I tried manually copying the static folder to various locations in webapps folder of tomcat, which did not help.

I can still access the REST end points.

Could some one please help on this?